# Object required Error 424

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

Im trying to retrieve a sheet name and store temporarily using the following function in `VBA`.

```
Function MySheet()

    MySheet = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name

End Function
```

But it keeps returning ***object required*** highlighting the
`MySheet = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name`.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dim ws as worksheet
set ws = activeworksheet

then try to get the name from ws.name

Answer (score 0):

You need the [Range.Parent property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980.aspx) of the [Application.Caller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193687.aspx) before you can retrieve the Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx).

```
Function MySheet()

    MySheet = Application.Caller.Parent.Name

End Function
```

This presupposes that you are using this on the worksheet as a UDF¹ worksheet function.

---

¹ <sub>A User Defined Function (aka UDF) is placed into a standard module code sheet. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to **Insert ► Module** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the function code into the new module code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s).</sub>

Comment: The Application.Caller would be the cell that the UDF function is placed in. The Parent of the worksheet cell is the worksheet and you can get its Name. If you are trying to call this from within a VBA module sub or somesuch then you need a better way of determining the Application.Caller because there is no worksheet cell calling the function.

Comment: So how do I find a better way? Very new to VBA and im very confused.

Comment: You have a workbook. The workbook has one or more worksheets. What is special about the worksheet you want the name of?